# Problem with defining a function which can execute object's methods and standalone functions

Tags: c++, templates

I am stuck at defining a function, which can execute standalone functions and methods of objects using templates.

```cpp
template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
void execute(Func&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    cout << "execute1" << endl;
    std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename Func, typename Obj, typename ...Args>
void execute(Func&& fun, Obj&& obj, Args&&... args)
{
    cout << "execute2" << endl;
    std::forward<decltype(obj)>(obj).fun(args...);
}

void fun()
{
    cout << "in fun()" << endl;
}

class A
{
public:
    void method()
    {
        cout << "in method()" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    execute(fun);
    execute(&A::method, std::move(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I pass fun() function as the parameter it executes correctly by first overload.

When I pass the method of object and the object on which this method should be called, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void execute(Func&&, Obj&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = void (A::*)(); Obj = A; Args = {}]’:
main.cpp:20:38: error: ‘class A’ has no member named ‘fun’
     std::forward<decltype(obj)>(obj).fun(args...);
```

I am new in templates so please be forgiving :)

Comment: Look up how to call a member function pointer. You need the `.*` operator and a couple parentheses.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke does exactly that.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, that did the job :) Sometimes its hard to understand where to put those parentheses.

Comment: Some very good reading on the topic: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

Both overloads are viable for `execute(&A::method, std::move(a));` and first one is a better match. So your error.

You might use SFINAE to discard the invalid overloads:

```
template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto execute(Func&& f, Args&&... args)
-> decltype(std::forward<Func>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    cout << "execute1" << endl;
    std::forward<Func>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename Func, typename Obj, typename ...Args>
auto execute(Func&& fun, Obj&& obj, Args&&... args)
-> decltype((std::forward<Obj>(obj).*fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);)
{
    cout << "execute2" << endl;
    (std::forward<Obj>(obj).*fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

As you might notice, I also fixed syntax of method call with method pointer (`.*` or `->*`).
Second overloads only handles reference object and not (smart) pointers. Other overload would be added to handle that.

In std, we have [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) (C++17) with does that and even more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am concerned how your code disables invalid overloads? As far as I see you have added auto return type deduce of execute() function and std::forward() on object. What change ensures this behaviour?

Comment: @Sielan: `decltype` allows the SFINAE, The trailing return type (`auto f() -> int`) is to allow to use parameters instead of using `std::decval<T>()`.

Comment: Ok, and what would be another methods to proper disabling invalid overloads?

Comment: `decltype` can be used with expression, else you need "traits". SFINAE can be done also with `std::enable_if` or similar. C++20 add `requires` to discard overload.